How do i make a faster C algorithm
i want to make an algorithm that filters some numbers like 101010101010101. numbers that have some patterns in them. but they are very large and i need 4 or 5 secounds to reach 100.000.000. and about 99.500.000 numbers are filtered out. the question is ,how can i reach 1.000.000.000.000.000 without waiting for months. i want the code to reach 100.000.000 in 0.4 secounds or less. i hope someone can help me. this is my code:
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <windows.h>

#define NUM_THREADS 8
#define MAX_NUM 100000ULL  

typedef struct {
    unsigned long long int start;
    unsigned long long int end;
    unsigned long long int count;
} ThreadData;

// Funktion zur Überprüfung auf aufeinanderfolgende Ziffern
bool has_consecutive_digits(const char* password, int length) {
    int len = strlen(password);
    for (int i = 0; i <= len - length; i++) {
        bool increasing = true, decreasing = true;
        for (int j = 0; j < length; j++) {
            if (password[i+j] != password[i] + j) increasing = false;
            if (password[i+j] != password[i] - j) decreasing = false;
        }
        if (increasing || decreasing) return true;
    }
    return false;
}

// Funktion zur Überprüfung auf zu viele Wiederholungen der gleichen Ziffer
bool has_repeated_digits(const char* password, int max_repeats) {
    int counts[10] = {0};
    int len = strlen(password);
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        counts[password[i] - '0']++;
        if (counts[password[i] - '0'] > max_repeats) return true;
    }
    return false;
}

// Funktion zur Überprüfung auf palindromische Muster
bool has_palindromic_pattern(const char* password, int length) {
    int len = strlen(password);
    for (int i = 0; i <= len - length; i++) {
        bool is_palindrome = true;
        for (int j = 0; j < length / 2; j++) {
            if (password[i+j] != password[i+length-1-j]) {
                is_palindrome = false;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (is_palindrome) return true;
    }
    return false;
}

// Funktion zur Überprüfung, ob das Passwort ein bekanntes Muster enthält
bool is_substring_of_common_patterns(const char* password) {
    const char* common_patterns[] = {
        "123456", "654321", "111111", "222222", "333333",
        "012345", "543210", "987654", "000000", "999999"
    };
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        if (strstr(password, common_patterns[i])) return true;
    }
    return false;
}

// Funktion zur Überprüfung auf abwechselnde Ziffern
bool has_alternating_digits(const char* password, int length) {
    int len = strlen(password);
    for (int i = 0; i <= len - length; i++) {
        bool valid = true;
        for (int j = 0; j < length; j++) {
            if ((j % 2 == 0 && password[i+j] != password[i]) ||
                (j % 2 == 1 && password[i+j] == password[i])) {
                valid = false;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (valid) return true;
    }
    return false;
}

// Funktion zur Überprüfung auf aufeinanderfolgende Blöcke von steigenden oder fallenden Ziffern
bool has_increasing_or_decreasing_blocks(const char* password, int block_size) {
    int len = strlen(password);
    for (int i = 0; i <= len - block_size; i += block_size) {
        if (has_consecutive_digits(password + i, block_size)) return true;
    }
    return false;
}

// Funktion zur Überprüfung auf spiegelbildliche Blöcke
bool has_mirrored_blocks(const char* password, int block_size) {
    int len = strlen(password);
    for (int i = 0; i <= len - 2 * block_size; i += block_size) {
        bool mirrored = true;
        for (int j = 0; j < block_size; j++) {
            if (password[i + j] != password[i + block_size * 2 - 1 - j]) {
                mirrored = false;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (mirrored) return true;
    }
    return false;
}

// Funktion zur Überprüfung, ob das Passwort ein zu einfaches Muster hat
bool is_pattern_too_simple(const char* password) {
    return has_consecutive_digits(password, 3) ||
           has_repeated_digits(password, 1) ||
           has_palindromic_pattern(password, 4) ||
           is_substring_of_common_patterns(password) ||
           has_alternating_digits(password, 4) ||
           has_increasing_or_decreasing_blocks(password, 2) ||
           has_mirrored_blocks(password, 4); // 3,1,3, ,4,2,4
}

// Funktion zur Überprüfung der Passwortgültigkeit
bool is_valid_password(const char* password) {
    return !is_pattern_too_simple(password);
}

DWORD WINAPI check_passwords(LPVOID arg) {
    ThreadData* data = (ThreadData*)arg;
    char password[7];  // Für Zahlen bis 999999 (6 Ziffern + Nullzeichen)
    data->count = 0;

    for (unsigned long long int i = data->start; i < data->end; i++) {
        sprintf(password, "%06llu", i);  // Erzeuge ein 6-stelliges Passwort
        if (is_valid_password(password)) {
            data->count++;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}

int main() {
    HANDLE threads[NUM_THREADS];
    ThreadData thread_data[NUM_THREADS];
    unsigned long long int range = MAX_NUM / NUM_THREADS;
    unsigned long long total_count = 0;

    // Starte die Threads
    for (int i = 0; i < NUM_THREADS; i++) {
        thread_data[i].start = i * range;
        thread_data[i].end = (i + 1) * range;
        threads[i] = CreateThread(NULL, 0, check_passwords, &thread_data[i], 0, NULL);
        if (threads[i] == NULL) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Error creating thread %d\n", i);
            return 1;
        }
    }

    // Warte auf Threads und sammle Ergebnisse
    for (int i = 0; i < NUM_THREADS; i++) {
        WaitForSingleObject(threads[i], INFINITE);
        DWORD exit_code;
        if (GetExitCodeThread(threads[i], &exit_code)) {
            total_count += thread_data[i].count;
        } else {
            fprintf(stderr, "Error getting thread exit code %d\n", i);
        }
        CloseHandle(threads[i]);
    }

    // Zeige die Gesamtanzahl der gültigen Passwörter an
    printf("Anzahl der gültigen Zahlen: %llu\n", total_count);

    return 0;
}

i tried to use multithreading and my code was about 10 times faster and an switched from int to unsigned long long int, that made my code a bit faster. i need at least a 10 times faster code than this one. i also tryed flags. i dont need to make this code in c ,if there is a faster language then please tell me.

Do not try to make code run faster with linear tricks.  Instead improve algorithm O().  First explain your algorithm used.

is_valid_password(password)) tests consecutive 6-digit numbers (as strings).  If "110000" fails, why test "110001", "110002", "110003".... "119999"?

With sprintf(password, "%06llu", i);, int len = strlen(password); is the same as int len = 6;.

If you reach 100.000.000 in 0.4 seconds, you will wait for months until 1.000.000.000.000.000.

@chux-ReinstateMonica It would be very difficult to implement an algorithm that doers not examine each string. Maybe not impossible, but each individual check present unique challenges.

After calling has_repeated_digits(password, 1) don't bother to call has_palindromic_pattern.

If the input is numeric then why are you using strings? Comparing integers is way more efficient than comparing strings.

It does not make sense to attempt to reach 1.000.000.000.000.000. Once the password is longer than 10 digits, by pigeonhole principle it will have repeats.

You could try sieving. If it's faster to generated passwords with the properties you're filtering than it is to test every one individually, then make an array and remove those  with the properties you're filtering.

There is no such thing as a "C algorithm".   There are algorithms, and you can implement them in C, but the language you use to implement an algorithm is not a trait of the algorithm.

For some of your individual checks, if a prefix of a password fails that check, then the full password will also fail that check.
For example, all passwords starting with "11" are invalid due to has_repeated_digits. So instead of checking all of them individually, you could skip the whole 110000-119999 range.
This will dramatically reduce a number of passwords that need to be considered -- as the passwords get longer, has_repeated_digits alone will exclude most of them from consideration.
